# What Do I Get If I Connect a Uplay Account?

Tags: xbox-360, ubisoft-connect, just-dance-2014

Just Dance 2014 (on the Xbox 360 if it matters) wants me to create a Uplay account (for Ubisoft) and connect it to the game.  What will be the in-game benefits if I do this? Will I get free songs or other DLC? Are there other ways to get those goods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Uplay's about page](http://uplay.ubi.com/en-GB/about) you can earn Units while playing games which you can exchange for in-game or real life rewards.

[This page](http://uplay.ubi.com/en-GB/game/just-dance-2014) says that on the Xbox 360 you can earn (Click on the XBox 360 logo):

- Follow the leader sweat version
- Just Dance 2014 Theme
- Just Dance 2014 Avatar
- Fine China - Dance Mash-up